# Search range of Numbers (using real numbers in the search)

Tags: search, vim, numbers, range

I want to search for a range of numbers (in VIM) but don't know how:

example:

- search numbers > 450,20
- search numbers > 1200 (or 1.200)
- search numbers > 10.000 AND < 1.000.000
- search numbers < 10

  -- all numbers must include decimal values p.e. 9,20 or 8,532 is a value less than 10
  -- all numbers can be inserted (searched) with or without the thousand separator, 
  there must be no difference in the output.

Can anyone help me with an example of code, how I can go on?
I already tried to create something like this, counting the number of digits but it doesn't work as I want, because in this way I cannot search values as > 90,50 or < 200 on the fly.

Comment: Can you post examples of what you have tried and in what way they failed?

Comment: sure, this is what I tried: `\d\{4,}\(,\d\+\)*\|\d*\(\.\d\{3}\)\+\(,\d\+\)*` (search numbers >=1000) - but I want to insert also numbers as 95,20 so I thought it is easier using numbers and not counting digits, but I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: I've read the whole day pages of websites about Vim but I can't find how to search a range of numbers on the fly (inserting the real numbers in the commandline). Maybe it is not possible to do in vim?

Comment: Seems like a task for a scripting language such as Perl or Python.  External scripts may be invoked from within Vim to act upon a range or selection.

Comment: I checked also perl, awk and sed. I haven't found something in these scripting languages what highlights the numbers in my vim document. Didn't search in Python: my VIM is not python compatible.

Comment: You didn't mention that highlighting was your objective.  I would use one of the scripting languages (which understand numeric values) to insert a tag by each found value.  Then use Vim to highlight search that tag.

Comment: sorry, you're right. I want to highlight it in search (/@) because I can copy all highlighted numbers with code I've already created a while ago. Nice idea to tag.. I'll try to understand it a bit more but it is new for me (as I don't know much about perl and python)

Comment: Just another question.. do you think it is possible by creating a list of numbers in a function (in vimscript) and search if a number is in the text? matchadd()??

Comment: Can anyone explain why there is a person who gives this question a negative vote?

Comment: This should be done by scripts.  But if you want Vim highlight search, for example > 4000.678, I got most by this search: `\v[4-9]\d{3,}[0-9.,;]*`

Answer (score 2):

Well **easily** you cannot ... But with efforts, you can do anything ! 
Searching a number > 450.20 is not a place for regex but:

`h perl-patterns`: Vim does not implement (unfortunately) `execution of arbitrary code in the regex:  (?{perl code})`. 
Meaning you must use some substitution (`s`) or global finding (`g`) to evaluate the match as a number and so easily discriminate it using VimL.

But you question ask for a `/` command. So let's do it with regex. The idea is to match:

- x > 1000: \d\d\d\d    (ie 4 digit)
- x > 500: [5-9]\d\d
- x > 460: 4[6-9]\d
- x > 450: 45[0-9]
- And more for after the colon

An example regex can take some place. Especially because I repeated the words boundary for each pattern.

\%(\%([^0-9.]\zs\|^)[5-9]\d\d\%(.\d*)\?\%(\ze\D\|$)\|\%([^0-9.]\zs\|^)4[6-9]\d\%(.\d*)\?\%(\ze\D\|$)\|\%([^0-9.]\zs\|^)45[1-9]\%(.\d*)\?\%(\ze\D\|$)\|\%([^0-9.]\zs\|^)\d*\d{4}\%(.\d*)\?\%(\ze\D\|$)\|\%([^0-9.]\zs\|^)450.[3-9]\d*\|\%([^0-9.]\zs\|^)450.2[1-9]\d*\|\%([^0-9.]\zs\|^)450.20\d*(\d\&[^0])\d*)

In details:

```
    " Numbers >= 500         (looking like '***')
    \%([^0-9.]\zs\|^\)[5-9]\d\d\%(\.\d*\)\?\%(\ze\D\|$\)

    " Or numbers >= 460      (looking like '4**')
    \|
    \%([^0-9.]\zs\|^\)4[6-9]\d\%(\.\d*\)\?\%(\ze\D\|$\)

    " Or numbers >= 451      (looking like '45*') 
    \|
    \%([^0-9.]\zs\|^\)45[1-9]\%(\.\d*\)\?\%(\ze\D\|$\)

    " Or numbers > 1000     (more than 4 digits)
    \|
    \%([^0-9.]\zs\|^\)\d*\d\{4}\%(\.\d*\)\?\%(\ze\D\|$\)

    " Or numbers >= 450.3    (450.******) 
    \|
    \%([^0-9.]\zs\|^\)450\.[3-9]\d*

    " Or numbers >= 450.21  (450.2*****) 
    \|
    \%([^0-9.]\zs\|^\)450\.2[1-9]\d*\)

    " Or numbers > 450.20   (450.20 + 0.00000002000) 
    \|
    \%([^0-9.]\zs\|^\)450\.20\d*\(\d\&[^0]\)\d*\)
```

I did make it with the following script:

```
" Search for all numbers in a range
"
" Source me then (better put the last command defintion in your vimrc, then
"
" :Isearch > 450.20
" :Isearch > 1000 < 1000000

function! search#char_range(char, dir)
  " Get string with range or '' if < 0 or > 9

  if a:dir
    let l:res = string( str2nr(a:char) + 1 )
    if (l:res == 10) | return '' | endif
    let l:res = '[' . l:res . '-9]'
  else
    let l:res = string( str2nr(a:char) - 1)
    if (l:res == -1) | return '' | endif
    let l:res = '[0-' . l:res . ']'
  endif

  return l:res
endfunction


function! search#isearch(num, dir, inc)
  " Search any number supp to 9
  " 
  " Number:     (number)  Limiting the range
  " Direction:  (boolean) Higher if true
  " Inclusive:  (boolean) Do the number is include >= or <= 
  "

  let l:start_of_number = '\%([^0-9.]\zs\|^\)'
  let l:pat_list = [l:start_of_number]

  " Get hight and low
  let l:list = split(a:num, '\.')
  let l:high = l:list[0]
  if (len(l:list) > 1)
    let l:low = l:list[1]
  else
    let l:low = ''
  endif


  " 1/ High loop
  " ~~~~~~~~~~~~
  for l:c in split(l:high, '\zs')
    " Get the higher range [-]
    let l:range = search#char_range(l:c, a:dir)
    if (l:range != '')
      let l:pat = l:pat_list[0] . l:range
      if (a:dir == 0 && l:pat_list[0] == l:start_of_number) 
        let l:pat .= '\?'
      endif
      call add(l:pat_list, l:pat)
    else
      if (a:dir)
        break
      else
        let l:pat_list[-1] .= '\d\?'
      endif
    endif

    " Add \d to previous guys
    for i in range(1, len(l:pat_list) - 2)
      let l:pat_list[i] .= '\d'
    endfor

    " Add to initial pattern
    let l:pat_list[0] .= l:c
  endfor

  " 1.2/ Include with more digit
  if a:dir
    let l:biggest =  l:start_of_number . '\d*\d\{' . string(len(l:pat_list)) . '}'
    call add(l:pat_list, l:biggest)
  endif

  " 1.3/ indlude rest (after .)
  for i in range(1, len(l:pat_list) - 1)
    " The last digit is non optional (otherwise can match all)
    if l:pat_list[i][-4:] == '\d\?'
      let l:pat_list[i] = l:pat_list[i][:-3]
    endif
    let l:pat_list[i] .= '\%(\.\d*\)\?\%(\ze\D\|$\)'
  endfor


  " 2/ Low loop
  " ~~~~~~~~~~~
  if (len(l:low) != '')
    let l:pat_list[0] .= '\.'
  else
    let l:pat_list[0] .= '\.\?'
  endif
  for l:c in split(l:low, '\zs')
    " Get the higher range [-]
    let l:cp1 = string( str2nr(l:c) + 1 )
    if (l:cp1 == 10) | break | endif
    call add(l:pat_list, l:pat_list[0] . '[' . cp1 . '-9]\d*')

    " Add to initial pattern
    let l:pat_list[0] .= l:c
  endfor

  " 2.2/ A very little drop
  let l:pat = l:pat_list[0] . '\d*\(\d\&[^0]\)\d*'
  call add(l:pat_list, l:pat)

  " 3/ Add the number itself
  if a:inc
    let l:pat = join(l:pat_list, '\|')
  else
    let l:pat = join(l:pat_list[1:], '\|')
  endif

  return l:pat
endfunction


function! search#wrapper(...)
  let l:pat = ''
  for l:i in range(len(a:000))
    " TODO check if there is a number after
    if (a:000[l:i] == '>=')
      if (l:pat != '') | let l:pat .= '\&' | endif
      let l:pat .= '\%(' . search#isearch(a:000[l:i+1], 1, 1) . '\)'
    elseif (a:000[l:i] == '>')
      if (l:pat != '') | let l:pat .= '\&' | endif
      let l:pat .= '\%(' . search#isearch(a:000[l:i+1], 1, 0) . '\)'
    elseif (a:000[l:i] == '<=')
      if (l:pat != '') | let l:pat .= '\&' | endif
      let l:pat .= '\%(' . search#isearch(a:000[l:i+1], 0, 1) . '\)'
    elseif (a:000[l:i] == '<')
      if (l:pat != '') | let l:pat .= '\&' | endif
      let l:pat .= '\%(' . search#isearch(a:000[l:i+1], 0, 0) . '\)'
    endif
  endfor

  let @/ = l:pat
endfunction

command! -nargs=* Isearch call search#wrapper(<f-args>) | normal n
```

You can find it (or a newer) on my github: https://github.com/tinmarino/Vimfiles/blob/master/autoload/search.vim

Answer (score 0):

I find that when I need to search for things bigger/smaller than a number, I also need to do something to the matches. For that case, [`submatch()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression) can be pretty useful.

Consider the case where I want to zero out all numbers bigger than 132 and less than 500.

Search for all numbers: `/\v<[0-9.]+>`

Zero all numbers >132 and <500: `:%s//\=submatch(0)>132 && submatch(0)<500 ? '0' : submatch(0)/g`

You can use that trick with `:global` as well if you want to work line-wise:

Mark lines that have numbers >132 and <500: `:%s//\=submatch(0)>132 && submatch(0)<500 ? 'deleteme' : submatch(0)/g`

Delete: `:g/deleteme/del`

---

Not the best solution for just *finding them*, unfortunately!